# Georeferencing images and losing quality in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I have several plans I need to georeference.  They start out like this:

[image]

But after georeferencing, the best I can get is this:

[image]

Using these settings:

[image]

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're setting the target resolution to 1 which is 1 meter per pixel. This is definitely low resolution compared to the original plan. Leave that option out and the output should be fine.

Comment: Perfect thanks @Techie_Gus. That must be the only experiment I didn't try!

Comment: @Ruth you're most welcome. We sometimes miss the obvious! If you feel my answer or any answer solved your issue, please consider marking it as  accepted by clicking the green check mark. It helps other people see that the solution works.